# laravel query with case statement in where clause append IS NULL after condition

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
->where([
         'er.id_user_request_to' => $nIdUser
       ])
->where(DB::raw('case WHEN ge.id_user IS NOT NULL THEN ge.id_user = '.$nIdUser.' ELSE 0 END'))
```

tried to print a query using following code

```
$qry = vsprintf(str_replace(array('%', '?'), array('%%', '"%s"'), $oEvents->toSql()), $oEvents->getBindings());
dd($qry);
```

This prints a query like

```
WHERE
(
    `er`.`id_user_request_to` = "6") 
    AND(
         CASE WHEN ge.id_user IS NOT NULL THEN ge.id_user = 6 ELSE 0 END
       )
) **IS NULL**
```

Not getting from where it adds **IS NULL** at the end of the query

Comment: can you provide the whole code instead of just where condition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace your DB::raw with whereRaw

```
->where([
     'er.id_user_request_to' => $nIdUser
   ])
->whereRaw(('case WHEN ge.id_user IS NOT NULL THEN ge.id_user = '.$nIdUser.' ELSE 0 END'))
```

I hope it help's

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO, SAVED MY LIFE. THANKS DEAR VIPUL PRAJAPATI :)